# Error while creating conda environment in windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I am trying to create conda virtual environment to use Tensorflow 1.14 inside of it. I have two environments already and they are working fine. But, when I ran the command `conda create -n bert python=3.6` I got the following error.

Os -Windows 10

Python = 3.7 default one

Conda Version = 4.7.11

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1062, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 80, in do_call
    module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_create.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .install import install
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import calculate_channel_urls, get_index
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\path_actions.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\download.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .session import CondaSession
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\session.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .adapters.s3 import S3Adapter
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\adapters\s3.py", line 14, in <module>
    boto3.client('s3')  # https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8993
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto3\__init__.py", line 91, in client
    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto3\session.py", line 263, in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\session.py", line 839, in create_client
    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 86, in create_client
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 328, in _get_client_args
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\args.py", line 85, in get_client_args
    client_cert=new_config.client_cert)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 259, in create_endpoint
    if not is_valid_endpoint_url(endpoint_url):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\utils.py", line 842, in is_valid_endpoint_url
    parts = urlsplit(endpoint_url)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 456, in urlsplit
    raise ValueError("Invalid IPv6 URL")
ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 150, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1354, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1065, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1109, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1120, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1190, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\path_actions.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\download.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .session import CondaSession
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\session.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .adapters.s3 import S3Adapter
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\adapters\s3.py", line 14, in <module>
    boto3.client('s3')  # https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8993
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto3\__init__.py", line 91, in client
    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto3\session.py", line 263, in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\session.py", line 839, in create_client
    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 86, in create_client
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 328, in _get_client_args
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\args.py", line 85, in get_client_args
    client_cert=new_config.client_cert)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 259, in create_endpoint
    if not is_valid_endpoint_url(endpoint_url):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\botocore\utils.py", line 842, in is_valid_endpoint_url
    parts = urlsplit(endpoint_url)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 456, in urlsplit
    raise ValueError("Invalid IPv6 URL")
ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL
```

How to solve this error? What is causing this?

Comment: Are you behind some kind of proxy now or did anything else about your network settings change between your last succesful environment creation and this one?

Comment: I do not know to be honest. Can you show me direction on how I can check if the proxy settings have been changed or not? @FlyingTeller

Comment: Only your IT department will be able to answer that for you

Comment: There is no IT department actually. I am alone in this. I used one website named kproxy.com last time to browse some torrent and after that, I am getting this error. But no idea what has changed since then. Any help and suggestion would help @FlyingTeller

Comment: Try completely reversing the steps you took to set up the proxy.

Comment: I did not take any steps. I just browsed using that kproxy.com website and then this error starts to shos up. Though I used `virtualenv` to create a virtual environment and it is working fine. @FlyingTeller

Answer (score 0):

saw "ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL"
try change you ip from ipv6 to ipv4, and install again.

Comment: what do you mean by change and install again? DO you mean to install anaconda again as that will create lot of trouble for me?